# Can this problem be solved using the implicit function theorem? If not, how?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined as 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} x^3+xy+1\\x+y+y^3+1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Show there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $(1,1)^T$, which is mapped bijectively to a neighborhood $V$ of $(3,4)^T$ by $f$. Find the derivative of the inverse $f^{-1}: V  \rightarrow U$ of f in the point $(3,4)^T$.

Explicitly calculating the inverse function is a mess.

My second attempt: define $g: \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $g((1,1),(3,4)) = 0$. Then the implicit function theorem gives us that there exists a mapping $\phi$ from a neighborhood of $(1,1)$ to a neighborhood of $(3,4)$, and it tells us that map is continuously differentiable. Using this approach I don't know how to show $f=\phi$, let alone that $\phi$ is bijective.

Is my approach wrong? If not how do I continue?

Comment: Why use the implicit function theorem if you can use the inverse function theorem? You find it very difficult to apply the implicit function theorem. The inverse function theorem would be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that $f'(1,1)$ is invertible. This shows the  existence of the sets $U $ and $V $.
The derivative of the inverse at $(3,4)^T $ is given by $f'(1,1)^{-1}$.